# Display values on heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I am working on a heatmap using heatmap.2 and would like to know if there is anyway to display the values on all heatmap positions. For example for the area representing "1" and rating I would like to display value "43", for "2" and privileges the value 51 and so on.

My sample data is as follows: [image]

```
            rating complaints privileges learning raises critical advance
      1      43         51         30       39     61       92      45
      2      63         64         51       54     63       73      47
      3      71         70         68       69     76       86      48
      4      61         63         45       47     54       84      35
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you mean? By providing the data object as the cellnote argument, the values are printed in the heatmap.

```
heatmap.2(data,           # cell labeling
          cellnote=data,
          notecex=1.0,
          notecol="cyan",
          na.color=par("bg"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to make the heatmap background transparent? It will be helpful for me to display on the values.

Comment: Sure - the default value of the col argument is heat.colors -- modify your code like this: `colors <- heat.colors(15, alpha = 0.5)`, `heatmap.2(data, cellnote=data, col=colors)`

Comment: For Cell labeling is there anyway not to display values that are 0 ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is just for "For Cell labeling is there anyway not to display values that are 0".

`cellnote=ifelse(data==0, NA, data)` will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In python when using seaborn.heatmap by simply using annot=True, all the values are displayed in the heatmap plot. See the example below:

[image]